# Effect of mean reverting Volatality in Black and Scholes?

Tags: black-scholes, delta-hedging, mean-reversion

Can someone please elaborate what would be the effect of a mean reverting volatility (instead of a constant volatility) in pricing options using BS ?
Also how would the greeks vary?

Comment: See this answer  [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/38972/8153).

Comment: If you mean a mean-reverting deterministic volatility (no volatility of volatility) then that still fits within the framework of Black-Scholes and all you have is Black-Scholes with deterministic volatility. But if you mean a mean-reverting stochastic volatility then you have to leave Black-Scholes world and look at Heston model or Schobel-Zhu etc.