# Converting Annual Vol to Instantaneous Vol with Mean Reversion

Tags: volatility, mean-reversion

[Options Pricing and Mean Reversion](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/45976/options-pricing-and-mean-reversion)

In the question above, in the accepted answer, the writer claims:

"For instance with a 100% mean reversion a 20% historical annual standard deviation would translate into approximately 30% instantaneous volatility."

I understand that the instantaneous volatility should be higher since annual changes will be less due to mean-reversion. But how did they get 20% annual std dev is approximately 30% instantaneous std dev?

Is there a formula I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the post that the other OP refers to in yet another link you find a formula: $$\hat{\sigma}=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-2\kappa T}}{2\kappa}}\,.$$ It matches those values for $T=1\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Is the formula backwards? Plugging in T = 1 and K = 1 (I assume 100% mean reversion means the rate coefficient is 1),  get about 0.66 for the square root term. But, doesn't sigma represent our normal (unadjusted) volatility of 20% so that the adjusted volatility is 20% * 0.66 which is obviously not 30%. So should the formula instead have sigma and sigma_hat switched?

Comment: No. $\sigma$ is the instantaneous volatility in the model that has mean reversion. As you wrote in OP that should be higher than the annual standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$ that this model produces. $\sigma=30\%$ gives $\hat{\sigma}=20\%\,.$